# How do I install an updated HPLIP on Rocky 8?

Tags: rocky-linux

I have an HP Laserjet Pro M148 multifunction printer/scanner that requires an updated hplip. The HP RPMs for Centos and RHEL are broken and HP's instructions for the manual build and install don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little out there on how to do this and questions on other forums were not helpful or unanswered, and locked so I couldn't respond. I got it to work and want to share the process that worked for me:

1. Download the tarball from [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip). Get the advanced tarball from the bottom. As of this writing, the link is https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.23.5/hplip-3.23.5.tar.gz/download.
2. Untar it into a folder and move to that folder.
3. Install the hplip packages to get all the dependencies:

   `sudo dnf install hplip hplip-gui`
4. Remove the hplip files, but leave the dependencies:

   `sudo rpm -e --nodeps hplip hplip-gui hplip-libs hplib-common`
5. Add other needed build dependencies. **Note:** This is my dev box, so if you run the configure command below and it breaks, you probably are missing a package that I have already installed (i.e.: libusb-devel). Just search for that devel package and install it, too:

   `sudo dnf install net-snmp-devel sane-backends-devel`
6. Configure the build for Qt5:

   `./configure --with-hpppddir=/usr/share/cups/model/HP --libdir=/usr/lib64 --prefix=/usr --disable-qt4 --enable-qt5 --disable-libusb01_build --enable-doc-build --enable-cups-ppd-install --disable-foomatic-drv-install --disable-foomatic-ppd-install --disable-hpijs-install --disable-udev_sysfs_rules --disable-policykit --disable-cups-drv-install --enable-hpcups-install --enable-network-build --enable-dbus-build --enable-scan-build --enable-fax-build`
7. Make and install:

   `make
   sudo make install`
8. Run hp-setup.

Happy printing (and scanning!)

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the srpm from hp or rhel and just upgrade the sources - maybe tuning a few things if needed?

Comment: I have thought of that, and I've repackaged more software into RPMs than I can count. Unfortunately I don't have time at the moment and this is my personal desktop, which I expect is the case with most people wanting to upgrade HPLIP. Of course it is better to have everything managed by the package manager, but sometimes you just need it to work *right now*! Thanks for the suggestion. Someday when I get some time, perhaps I'll work with the RPM maintainer to update it.

Comment: It was more about saving time as grabbing the spec and just changing the version often mostly works with minor tuning which might have been simpler in addition to being RPM managed but whatever works for you 